# Differences between Gcd and factoring

Tags: rsa

please can someone explain to me the difference between the following. Using two different numbers I. E  one is the rsa key and the other a number working from 2 upwards to work out the Gcd, until the prime is reached. Or using factorisation on a key. Are both these methods brute force? Do they both take a long time?

Comment: I see, sorry I'm new at this, I think I'm asking a few different questions in one go. Firstly is using the gcd method the same as factorisation?  Secondly is using the gcd method to check every number still brute forcing? Is this quicker than factorisation? Can it be done on a home computer? There was an experiment done a while ago where a number of keys were cracked  due to sharing a gcd, just wanted a bit more info on the implications of that.

Comment: @RichieRoll The question is probably closed already (I can't see this from my android app). If it is - you need to create a new question, if it's not - you need to edit the question body, instead of generating more and more comments.   If you don't understand what you're asking - provide a link to where you've read about what you call "gcd method" (in relation to rsa) or "experiment .. where keys were cracked due to sharing a gcd". Someone in the know might then figure out what is it you're talking about.

Comment: I assume the attack is incrementing $i$ and computing gcd($i$,$n$) until it gives a factor of $n$. If that's the case please edit the question, but the short answer is: it's not better than simply trying to divide $n$ by $i$, and it's just brute force.

Comment: Hey, sorry, stack won't let me ask another question, any chance you would know if it takes less time to subtract a sum rather than factor?

Answer (score 2):

> Or using factorisation on a key. Are both these methods brute force?

There is not *the* factorization method. There are different algorithms for different situations, depending on the number you are given and the properties you know / suspect from it.

> one is the rsa key and the other a number working from 2 upwards to work out the Gcd, until the prime is reached. Are both these methods brute force?

This is one algorithm to factor a number and it is slower than standard [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) because computing a GCD is slower than computing a division (because it involves many divisions). However during prime generation it is commonly seen that a GCD is computed between a product of many primes and a prime candidate to quickly rule out many small prime factors.

> Do they both take a long time?

Yes, for well chosen numbers all known factorization techniques take a long time.

> Can it be done on a home computer?

Yes, you can chose numbers for which standard factorization methods as well as this gcd-based one will terminate in a reasonable amount of time on a home computer.